# Phalcon 4 How to get URL of current page?

Tags: php, phalcon

In phalcon 3.4 we had the below function to get the current URL,

```
$current_url = $this->router->getRewriteUri();
```

However, it seems to be that, it was dropped in version 4.0 however there is no direct corresponding function for this i could find. Can you please let me know how to change this function to adapt to version 4.0+ Or should i just use the direct way (I usually hate to mix things up) but looks like no other choice

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `Phalcon\Http\Request::getURI()` but it uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if your project is not on root path you may want to use `$_GET['_url']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$this->request->getURI()` to obtain it as string (same as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), like:

```
/mycontroller/action?someparam=value
```

... or the `$this->request->getQuery()`  if you want to get it parsed, like:

```
array(2) {
  ["_url"]=>
  string(13) "/mycontroller/action"
  ["someparam"]=>
  string(2) "value"
}
```